# jQuery bootstrap multiselect dropdown not getting loaded

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use bootstrap multiselect plugin in one of my ASPX pages. Along with the multiselect plugin I have several other jQuery controls in the same page (like autocomplete textbox etc) and some client side validations as well. Following is my bootstrap multiselect code:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server"> 

    <link href="Styles/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="Styles/StyleSheetMasterDataForm.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles/bootstrap-3.1.1.min.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles/bootstrap-multiselect.css" type="text/css" /> 

   <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.11.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/bootstrap-2.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>   



    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
        $(document).ready(function () {            
          debugger;
           $("[id*=ListBoxProdEngine]").multiselect({
                includeSelectAllOption: true
            });
 });                     //Ending document.ready
    </script>
```

HTML code:

```
<tr>
              <td class="style6"><div class="style8"><strong>Product Engine:</strong></div></td>

              <td class="style2"><asp:ListBox ID="ListBoxProdEngine" multiple="multiple" runat="server"></asp:ListBox></td>
            </tr>
```

Code behind:

```
private void PopulateProductEngine()
        {
            try
            {
                ProductEngine objProductEngine = new ProductEngine();
                ListBoxProdEngine.DataSource = objProductEngine.GetProductEngine();
                ListBoxProdEngine.DataTextField = "ProductEngine";
                ListBoxProdEngine.DataValueField = "ProductEngine";
                ListBoxProdEngine.DataBind();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ErrorHandler.ReportError(ex); //Notifies technical team about the error
                Server.ClearError();
                Response.Redirect(string.Format("Error.aspx?aspxerrorpath={0}", Request.Url.PathAndQuery));
            }
        }
```

The error encountered is in the "multiselect" function in document.ready. Please help.

Comment: and what is this error? can you not just do: `$("#ListBoxProdEngine").multiselect({includeSelectAllOption: true});`

Comment: I want to move this control to user control after I successfully implement it in one page.Even though I use it as $("[id*=ListBoxProdEngine]") I am getting the Error:Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: If you're putting this in a user control does that mean you plan on having multiple instances of the mutiselect on the page? If that's the case you may want to consider adding a class to the `Listbox` and have your selector use something like `$(".myListboxClass").multiselect({includeSelectAllOption: true});`